# How to set custom DataGridView Borders in C# winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am stuck in this if any body can help i want to print the datagridview header row with a single dashed line below only like:

```
Name              ID
---------------------
```

And print the items without anyborders like this

```
Name              ID
---------------------
Abc               21
```

I used this code

```
dgvmain.RowHeadersBorderStyle = DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.Single;
dgvmain.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None;
```

Where `dgvmain` is the name of my `DataGridView`
Any help thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry didnt get you @King King

Comment: I think you should post some screen shot (at least a link to the screen shot of what you want).

Comment: put a screenshot of what you want or what you got

Comment: This some thing i want to print on paper. Printing is allright with me just need to change the style with fancy borders. Hope u understant

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310695/dotted-horizontal-grid-lines-in-wpf-datagrid

Comment: @JamesJeffery that's `WPF`, here is `winforms`.

Comment: @ROM might be worth putting that in the question.

Comment: Yes Thats WPF i want it in winforms

Comment: @ROM in which case you're probably going to have to create a custom control that inherits DataGridView

Answer (score 9):

You need to do a little custom painting by adding code to the `CellPainting` event handler. For setting the cells border to `None`, use `CellBorderStyle`:

```
dataGridView1.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None;

// CellPainting event handler for your dataGridView1
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == -1 && e.ColumnIndex > -1)
    {
       e.Handled = true;
       using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor))
       {
         e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, e.CellBounds);
       }
       using (Pen p = new Pen(Brushes.Black))
       {
         p.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;
         e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, new Point(0, e.CellBounds.Bottom-1), new Point(e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom-1));
       }
       e.PaintContent(e.ClipBounds);
    }
}
```

[image]