# Creating bottom and right cell borders in C# DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, border

I'm  looking for help in creating a custom border for my `DataGridView`. What I'm looking for is to create a style where the column header cells have a solid, bottom border only and the row headers have a solid, right border only.

I have managed to draw the columns headers border successfully by adapting [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297083/how-to-set-custom-datagridview-borders-in-c-sharp-winforms). However, I am struggling to draw the row headers border.

The image below shows what I have so far. As you can see, the column headers have a solid black line as their border. The red  line is what I've managed to draw for the row headers, but I can't seem to get the line to extend over all rows in the table. In other words, **how do I get the red line to draw in the row headers cell for all rows?**

[image: current border example]

This is the event handler I'm currently using

```
private void TransitionTable_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == -1 && e.ColumnIndex > -1){
        e.Handled = true;
        using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(activeTable.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor)){
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, e.CellBounds);
        }

        using (Pen p = new Pen(Brushes.Black)){
             p.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Solid;
              e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, new Point(0, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1), new Point(e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1));

            //This `if` statement is what I've managed to get working, but I can't get it to draw the line on all rows.
            //It only draws in the first row
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
            {
                Pen b = new Pen(Brushes.Red);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(b, new Point(e.CellBounds.Right - 1, 0), new Point(e.CellBounds.Right - 1, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1));
            }
        }
        e.PaintContent(e.ClipBounds);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Comment: @TaW Yes, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two issues:

**1)** You start with a condition that only applies to the column header row (-1). You will need two code blocks with separate conditions for the row- and the column-headers, maybe like this:

```
private void TransitionTable_CellPainting(object sender, 
                                          DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(TransitionTable.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor))
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, e.CellBounds);

    e.PaintContent(e.ClipBounds);

    if (e.RowIndex == -1)  // column header
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1, 
                                        e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1);
    }
    if (e.ColumnIndex == -1)  // row header (*)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, e.CellBounds.Right - 1, 0, 
                                      e.CellBounds.Right - 1, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1);
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Or you could avoid owner-drawing the regular cells by wrapping the whole block in a `or-condition`like this :

```
if (e.RowIndex == -1 || e.ColumnIndex = -1) 
{
     all the code above in here!
}
```

**2)** Your code and your screenshot do look as if you actually don't **have** any `RowHeaders`, though, and draw your line in the **first data column**. If that is what you want, ignore the last remark and simply change the condition (*****) to

```
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Tried both above methods, the red border doesn't appear at all for either.

Comment: Hm, that's strange, it works fine here as you can see. Are you sure about wanting to have that line on the __rowheaders__? Your code doesn't do that at all. Seems you don't even __have__ rowheaders but draw in the (header of) the __first column__ instead. If you want that simply change the condition to `if (e.ColumnIndex ==  0)`. In that case the wrapper from my last remark doesn't make sense.

Comment: Maybe the OP wants the red line for all rows. Anyway the solution guides the OP to do same thing for all rows or somewhere else.

Comment: I'm an idiot, that is indeed the first data column. I'll try this later and get back to you.

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thanks for pointing out that I wasn't actually applying anything to the row headers, but the first data column.